# Splitting a named object into subsets and updating references to it. What is this process called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a database query. I've named it `roads_vw`.

After the query had been used for some time, I realized that I needed to split the query into subsets: `roads_with_spatial_column_vw` and `roads_without_spatial_colum_vw`. Once the change was made, I needed to update anything that referenced the old query to use the name of one of the new queries.

This might seem a bit silly, but it happens all the time when I'm designing things, especially databases.

Is there a word or phrase that I could use to succinctly describe this situation?

Comment: It sounds rather like [refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025844/what-is-refactoring-and-what-is-only-modifying-code)...

Comment: Refactoring is a good word since you're renaming and updating the references accordingly. Or you can may be use data segregation. Actually you shouldn't create two tables. You should keep the roads table and assign properties to the data. So you don't need to update the references.

Comment: This sounds a bit like de-normalization.  In a normalized database schema you’d have a separate table forX and just include the ids from the roads table that had that attribute.

Comment: @Jim and Lucky: You make fair points. In hindsight, I shouldn't have dumbed-down my real-world example. I thought dumbing it down to the `roads_with_x` example would make the question simpler, but it didn't really. I've reverted the question back to my real-world example (although it is now quite specific/technical). I'm hoping the the root question is still simple enough.

Comment: Disaggregating?  I've heard the word but I don't know if what I heard was a correct use of the word.

Comment: I agree with @Jim on this one: You are de-normalizing. Further discussion is for Code Review or StackOverflow, but perhaps it would be better to create two views of the existing table.

Comment: There's also https://dba.stackexchange.com/ which is especially for all things related to databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called "partitioning". Colloquially you may also hear it called `sharding`. In PostgreSQL 10, you do it like,

```
CREATE TABLE roads (
  -- stuff
  has_x bool NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LIST (has_x);

CREATE TABLE roads_with_x
   PARTITION OF roads
   FOR VALUES IN (true);

CREATE TABLE roads_without_x
   PARTITION OF roads
   FOR VALUES IN (false);
```

This is also nice because it obscures the underpinnings eliminating the need for you to write triggers.

Comment: To be fair to Evan, this answer pertains to an old example that I had in my question. In a stoke of bad luck, I changed the example in my question (for reasons described in the comments) right when he was in the process of answering the question. I think the answer still generally holds though, and will mark it as correct.